# Pose mode in 2.78 considerably slower than 2.77

Tags: pose-mode

I recently updated to 2.78 due to getting a new graphics card that was not supported by 2.77, but I've run into an issue with pose mode. Previously on 2.77, I could run it at full speed in material view, but since 2.78, it dips into the low 20s or high teens FPS when moving objects. It goes as far as locking up the programme if I try to type in scale factors.

I know that switching to texture/solid mode is a workaround for this, but I would much rather know if there is a way to actually fix this issue.

Comment: How many times recently (today) have you gone back and forth to seriously test this behaviour on the same file?  You should also be aware that often times discussing hardware issues directly is not the emphasis of this forum.

Comment: This is not a hardware issue, I have tested it just today. The reason I mentioned my hardware upgrade is that I need to use 2.78 now instead of 2.77, since it lacks the kernels for my GPU. I tested the same files on both versions, 2.77 runs consistently better than 2.78.

Comment: Please specify what kind of system you are using, what graphics card, etc

Comment: AMD FX-8350 running at 4.0GHz, GTX 1050 Ti 4GB VRAM and 16GB of RAM.